# connecting dialogflow voicebot to twilio number

Tags: python, twilio, dialogflow-es

I am a noob to dialogflow as well as twilio. I am trying to connect my dialogflow bot to a Twilio number. 
I got a twilio number and i am using dialogflow small talk set of intents.

What are the steps to connect a dialogflow (voice)bot to a twilio number with voice (not sms, or chat messaging) ?

On twilio side, i found this code 
    from flask import Flask
    from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Gather, Redirect, VoiceResponse, Say
    app = Flask(**name**)

```
@app.route("/answer", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def answer_call():
    """Respond to incoming phone calls with a brief message."""
    # Start our TwiML response
    response = VoiceResponse()

    # Read a message aloud to the caller

    gather = Gather(input='speech',action='some_url')
    gather.say('Welcome to Paradise, please tell us why you\'re calling')
    response.append(gather)

    return str(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

1) I understood that i should put the url of my dialogflow bot into the action argument. Am I right?

2) If yes, where do i find this url? Is it related to this ? => https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent

3) Then, what would be the session name?

I am trying to use the box on the right "Try this API": but whatever string i write, the output received is :
"name does not match pattern: /^projects/[^/]+/agent/sessions/[^/]+/contexts/[^/]+$/"

As mentionned i am a newby, so any insights on the above would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/autopilot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've not worked with Dialogflow and Twilio Voice directly (I prefer to connect voice with [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/autopilot) as it works out of the box). However I know that there is no direct connect between Twilio Voice and Dialogflow.

You are on the right track though. Using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) will capture the user's speech and translate it to text (actually using Google's Cloud Speech API). That text will be sent to your `action` URL as the `SpeechResult`. You can't connect that directly to your Dialogflow API endpoint because Dialogflow will expect the parameter to be different and Twilio will expect the result to be [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml).

Instead you will want to setup the action endpoint on your own server, retrieve the `SpeechResult` and then send that on to Dialogflow for the result. You might find it easier to interact with the Dialogflow API by installing the [Dialogflow Python client](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2) and using it to send the request (check out the [documentation here](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). Once you get the result back from Dialogflow you can then use it to construct TwiML to create a new `<Gather>` for further input or just a `<Say>` to return the response.

Let me know if this points you in the right direction.